# creating border type elements in EA

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

In Enterprise Architect there are Elements which contains border type Elements.So using Addin how to add the border type elements to the elements and reflect in the diagram.Ie creating port type elements and adding to the diagram in EA using EA Api

Answer (score 1):

Adding a port to a diagram is just like "normal" elements, except you need the embedding element be placed first. E.g.:

```
pos = "l=300;r=400;t=-400;b=-470";
dia_obj = diagram.DiagramObjects.AddNew (pos, "");
dia_obj.ElementID = element.ElementID;
dia_obj.Update ();
pos = "l=393;r=408;t=-434;b=-449";
dia_obj = diagram.DiagramObjects.AddNew (pos, "");
dia_obj.ElementID = embedded.ElementID;
dia_obj.Update ();
Repository.ReloadDiagram (diagram.DiagramID);
```

Note that there are a couple of EA versions which are buggy and did not place the embedded element correctly and rather used a (random) top left position in the embedding element. The latest 12.1 should have fixed that (without having tested it again).